# How can I run a shell script on session end?

Tags: shutdown, reboot, logout, automatic

In a [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457329), I found out how to shut down *all* instances of running VMs started through [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com). I'd like to call that script when logging out of my Desktop Manager which is currently Cinnamon.

Some have pointed to another similar similar, but I did not understand the selected answer(s) enough to be able to solve my issue and put anything into action. The comments below point to `start on stopping lightdm`. This sounds like what I'm looking for. **That is how can I run a script to stop all VMs (called: stop-vagrant.sh) when my log out of my desktop manager (`start on stopping lightdm`)?**

Comment: try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30383/best-way-to-make-a-shutdown-hook) link

Comment: Logout is trickier, because Upstart has events for a GUI logout, but not for a TTY/SSH one. Otherwise @Letizia's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: Can it be connected to the stopping of the desktop manager? I appreciate @Letizia 's suggestion but I didn't understand those answers to a point where I could begin to take action. Do I place start on / stop on commands in .bashrc/.bash_profile? Do I append that phrase to the start of a command `vagrant up stop on <condition>`.

Comment: @Richard yes.. Something like `start on stopping lightdm`

Comment: But do I key that phrase into the shell or profile? And how do those four words get associated with my vagrant-stop.sh script? @muru

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is create an [Upstart job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#task). Let us say your script for stopping VMs is available at `/some/path/vagrant-stop.sh`.

Depending on the exact nature of your VMs (are they run only when you're logged into a GUI, or are they run when the system starts up, etc.), you could use either a System job or a Session job. For the case where the VMs are run only when you're logged into a GUI, you can use a session job, a simple example of which I'll present here:

Create a file in `~/.config/upstart` with a `.conf` extension (use your favourite editor):

```
vim ~/.config/upstart/stop-vms.conf
```

The content would be:

```
description "Give your task a description"
start on session-end

task

exec /some/path/vagrant-stop.sh
```

Run `initctl check-config` to see if there are any errors.

Now, you can stop your VMs with (pardon the phrasing):

```
start stop-vms
```

Upstart will automatically run this when you log out.

Comment: What will be the systemd way of doing this? I mean I need to run a script at logout, _not shutdown event_

Comment: @Anwar I haven't tested it, but I'd think a user service, say `~/.config/systemd/user/foo.servce`, with an `ExecStop=some-command` would be enough (since systemd stops all user services on logout, unless the user has linger enabled)

Comment: hmm.. thanks for quick response. I tested with user service, but couldn't get it to work. for some reason the service was active. Basically what I wanted was running two separate script with systemd upon login and logout (graphical would be better)

Comment: @Anwar which version of Ubuntu? If you're on 16.04, Upstart user sessions are still available.

Comment: I've on 17.10 and more importantly, I don't want to use upstart etc.